# push data into ng-repeat became blank data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('tContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$stateParams','$timeout','getTopicContent', function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$timeout,getTopicContent){

    $scope.ionLoader = true;
    $scope.threadContent = [];

     var promise = getTopicContent.request($stateParams.topicId).then(function(response){
        $scope.threadContent = response.data;

        totalPages = response.data[0].totalPages;

        console.log(response.data);


    }).finally(function(){
        $scope.ionLoader = false;
    });

    $scope.loadPages = function() {
        if(totalPages > 1){
                $http({
                url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
                method: "GET",
                params: {topicId: $stateParams.topicId}
            }).success(function(data){
                 promise.then(function(none) { 
                    $scope.threadContent.push(data); 
                    console.log(data);
                 });
            });
        }
    }
```

In the both console.log(data) above, the result are the same, that means my data is not empty. I wish to achieve infinite scrolling it pushed the blank data.

Comment: $scope.threadContent.push(data.data)?

Comment: @cbass still the same.. blank..

Comment: could you provide html template with ng-repeat and calling of  loadPages